# How can I recover deleted data from a partition

Tags: python, data-recovery

I want to recover deleted data from a partition with the help of a Python program.

I know that on deletion, only the inode information of that file is deleted, but the bits are not overwritten by zeroes on deletion. However, how do I access the partition and retrieve data from there?

I want to deal with file deletion. I am using ext4 filesystem.

This is part of an assignment in a course called Cyber Forensics. However, my teacher doesn't know how to perform this task. We are being asked to use ready-made tools for recovery, which doesn't make any sense for us as students, as we don't get to see the source. So, I want to be able to write an equivalent recovery tool.

Comment: Deleting a partition (partition table entry) and a file (inode entry) are two completely different operations.  Which one are you wanting to deal with?  And what filesystem are you using and what options (journaling, etc.)?  Also, are you trying to undo data loss you've already experienced, or are you wanting to create a tool for future use?  Please edit your question to add all relevant details.

Comment: You access the partition via its block device (e.g., `/dev/sda1`). And from there, your program needs to understand the filesystem data structures, etc.

Comment: I want to deal with file deletion. I am using ext4 filesystem.

Sorry, but I do not know about options like journaling.

Comment: So you're trying to create a utility for future use?   Please edit your question to add all relevant details.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: Try an open-source ready-made tool? I think [`ddrescue`](https://github.com/mruffalo/ddrescue) fits that description. You should also look at [`wipefs`](https://gitorious.org/util-linux-ng/util-linux-ng/source/6c7d5ae9a2338be35cfab0fd8379a9f58c4f8c36:misc-utils/wipefs.c)

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend that you start with existing tools.  As they are all open source, you can see how they are written.

If you really want to write your own utility from scratch, you'll probably need to start with reading and understanding this page:

https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout

That page may not be complete, and referencing actual kernel driver code may be necessary.

Comment: Can you suggest a tool? On searching I found 'TestDisk'. Do you have any other suggestion that I should use?

Comment: Not from experience, but extundelete and ext3grep seem to be popular.

Comment: @Rayu [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) is another.